# Fortran function specifying size of input and output arrays and gfortran bounds check

Tags: arrays, function, fortran

Let's assume I have the following fortran program

```
program foobar
implicit none

interface
    pure function foo (var1, var2) result(ans)
        implicit none
        integer, dimension(:),          intent(in) :: var1
        integer, dimension(size(var1)), intent(in) :: var2
        integer, dimension(product(var1 + var2)) :: ans
    end function foo

    pure function bar (n, var1, var2) result(ans)
         implicit none
         integer,                        intent(in) :: n
         integer, dimension(:),          intent(in) :: var1
         integer, dimension(size(var1)), intent(in) :: var2
         integer, dimension(n)                      :: ans
   end function bar
end interface

write (*,*) foo([1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2])
! write (*,*) bar(27, [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2])   
end program foobar

pure function foo (var1, var2) result(ans)
     implicit none
     integer, dimension(:),          intent(in) :: var1
     integer, dimension(size(var1)), intent(in) :: var2
     integer, dimension(product(var1 + var2))   :: ans
     ans = 0
end function foo

pure function bar (n, var1, var2) result(ans)
     implicit none
     integer,                        intent(in) :: n
     integer, dimension(:),          intent(in) :: var1
     integer, dimension(size(var1)), intent(in) :: var2
     integer, dimension(n) :: ans
     ans = 0
end function bar
```

If I compile this code with

```
gfortran -fcheck=all -o bbb bbb.F08
```

then I get the following error during execution

> Fortran runtime error: Array bound mismatch for dimension 1 of array 'var2' (0/3)

If I omit the -fcheck=all option, the code compiles and runs just fine. If I comment the first write in the main program and uncomment the second one, the code compiles and runs fine, regardless of whether I use the -fcheck=all option. I couldn't check with other compilers, since gfortran is the only one that I have access to at the moment.

As far as I understand, the compiler cannot determine the size of the array and therefore the check fails during runtime. Is this interpretation correct? Secondly, is there some rule as to what I may place inside dimension() declarations, such that the compiler can still do some bounds checking at runtime? Should I always pass explicitly the size of an array? That way I could probably get around these issues, but it would make calling these functions quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to answer what can be in a `dimension` declaration for your result variable `ans`.

`ans` is an explicit-shape array, so the bound you provide must be a *specification expression*.  Because it is a result variable it needn't be a constant expression, just a restricted expression.  Details of how a restricted expression is made up are given in Fortran 2008 7.1.11.

Let's look at the things that make up the expression `product(var1 + var2)`.  If that's a restricted expression, you're fine to use it as you have.

`var1` and `var2` are dummy variables without the `intent(out)` and `optional` attributes.  So that's good.  What's next?

`+` here is the intrinsic operation.  Tick.  Making `var1+var2` a restricted expression.

`product` is a standard intrinsic function which is not a specification inquiry function, and it has argument a restricted expression, and its result in this case is a scalar integer epxression.

So, all that said: it's fine.

And, as Vladimir F says: it's a compiler bug.  This just confirms it's not a programmer bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is a  compiler bug, already fixed in recent versions. On my computer it fails with gfortran 4.7.and runs OK with pre-release of gfortran-5.

Comment: With ifort14.0, attaching -check gives an error message "catastrophic error: Internal compiler error: ..." Even if I moved foo() and bar() inside a module and delete their interfaces, still the same error (if -check is given). On the other hand, Oracle Fortran compiler 12.4 (for Linux) had no problem with -C. So mysterious...

Comment: "Internal compiler error", obviously these corners are not too well tested in some compilers.

Comment: It fails for me with gfortran 5.1 from the TDM 64bit distribution on Windows 8.1 and gfortran 4.8 on OpenSuse 13.2